# Stuck with Regex Replace

Tags: python, python-re

I am trying to replace "[!" **at the start of the string only** with "(".
The same holds for "!]" with ")", only at the end.

```
import re
l=["[!hdfjkhtxt.png!] abc", "hghjgfsdjhfg [a!=234]", "[![ITEM:15120710/1]/1587454425954.png!]", "abc"]
p=[re.sub("\[!\w+!]", '', l[i]) for i in range(len(l)) if l[i] != ""]
print(p)
```

the required output is

```
["(hdfjkhtxt.png)", "hghjgfsdjhfg [a!=234]", "([ITEM:15120710/1]/1587454425954.png)", "abc"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex placing parens around content between matching pairs of '[!', '!]'

```
# content between '[!' and '!]' in in capture group
[re.sub(r"\[!(.*)!\]", lambda m: "(" + m.group(1) + ")", s) for s in l]
```

**Output**

```
['(hdfjkhtxt.png) abc', 'hghjgfsdjhfg [a!=234]', '([ITEM:15120710/1]/1587454425954.png)', 'abc']
```

Comment: Interesting: this (like my version) doesn't produce the "output required" 

Comment: @wolf-liked your version also (especially the explanatino detail), thus my upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You describe your task as a combination of two parts:

- substitute `[!` by `(` and
- substitute `!]` by `)`.

If this can be done separately or has only to be done simultaneously is addressed later.

### First approach

Think if [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) could do the job. It looks quite convenient and you don't even need to `import re`:

```py
[e.replace("[!", "(").replace("!]", ")") for e in l]
```

BTW: there is no need to exclude the empty string (`""`) from the replacement because it's formally replaced by `""` and will be technically skipped anyway.

#### Regex version

```py
[re.sub(r"\[!", "(", re.sub(r"!\]", ")", e)) for e in l]
```

#### Decomposition

The nested substitutions may not look like *two steps* on first glance, so see the following example

```py
import re

l = [
    "[!hdfjkhtxt.png!] abc",
    "hghjgfsdjhfg [a!=234]",
    "[![ITEM:15120710/1]/1587454425954.png!]", 
    "abc"
]

for e in l:
    sd = re.sub(r"\[!", "(", e)
    sd = re.sub(r"!\]", ")", sd)
    print(e, " --> ", sd)
```

that produces this output:

```
[!hdfjkhtxt.png!] abc  -->  (hdfjkhtxt.png) abc
hghjgfsdjhfg [a!=234]  -->  hghjgfsdjhfg [a!=234]
[![ITEM:15120710/1]/1587454425954.png!]  -->  ([ITEM:15120710/1]/1587454425954.png)
abc  -->  abc
```

See the [**re.sub** documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) for correct argument use.

#### Refinement

Because `re.sub` also supports back references, it's also possible to do the replacement of paired brackets.

```py
re.sub(r"\[!(.+)!\]", r"(\1)", e)
```

### Choose wisely!

It's important to be careful reading the **actual requirement**. If you have to replace bracket pairs, use the second, If you have to replace the sequences regardless of occurrences being paired or not, use the first. Otherwise you are doing it wrong.

### Escaping

Keep in mind that that backslash (`\`), as an escape character, has to be doubled in normal string literals, an alternative is to prefix the string literal by `r`. Doubling the backslash (or the `r` prefix) is optional in all but the last example because `\[` and `\]` have no function in python whereas `\1` is the code for `SOH` ([the control char in ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#Basic_ASCII_control_codes)) or `U+0001` ([the Unicode point](https://www.compart.com/de/unicode/U+0001)).